# "Se cancelo una tarea" al mandar mas de 3 peticiones con HttpClient

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo peticiones a una API mediante un servicio de Windows, la petición se hace correctamente cuando envió 1-3 consecutivas, mi conflicto surge cuando se realizan mas de 3 peticiones ya que me regresa la excepción "Se cancelo una tarea", cabe mencionar que al momento de lanzar las 5 peticiones las 3 primeras pintan eventos y para las 2 ultimas los eventos tardan en pintarse (imagino es por el `timeout`).

Otro punto importante a mencionar creo yo es que realice una prueba mandando peticiones cada minuto y estas se realizan correctamente.

El TimeSpan lo he cambiado varias veces  desde 10 segundos hasta 1 minuto y el error sigue persistiendo.

```
        HttpClient clientNotifiaction = new HttpClient();
        clientNotifiaction.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        clientNotifiaction.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Header", Header);
        clientNotifiaction.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        clientNotifiaction.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

        StringContent content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage request = await clientNotifiaction.PostAsync(url, content);
        response.ResponseMessage = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```